# How to add decoration to OS specific cursor in SWT

Tags: java, image, cursor, swt

I'd like to change the cursor on an SWT Composite to add a small image to the standard OS arrow cursor, in the bottom right corner for instance.

I imagine it will mean somehow getting hold of the Image and X,Y hotspot of the cursor but I can't figure how do do that. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Following the comment this has spawned [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166262/how-to-combine-images-to-use-as-swt-cursor)

Comment: You can create a new cursor using the `Cursor` class but there is no way to access the image for an existing cursor.